# How to solve a simple recurrence relation in R?

Tags: r, sequence, math

I want to work out a simple recurrence relation in R but I cant find resources anywhere online that allows me to do this.

something simple like

for $n=1,2,3$

$X_0=3$

$X_n=X_{n-1}+5$
then print all $X_n$

I understand the basics for a for loop but it doesnt work for the left hand side of the loop, like i cant simply have

$for(i \hspace{2mm} in  \hspace{2mm} 1:3)$

{
$X_0=3$

$X_n=X_{n-1}+5$
}

Answer (score 0):

Like with any other language, you could use a for loop but then you're not using recursivity. The recursive version:

```
f <- function(n) { if (n==0) 3 else f(n-1)+5 }
```